# How to implement unread/new posts/comments in NoSQL document store like Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I've searched and didn't find any exact answer to this common problem.

I would like to show to users new/unread posts in a way that they get for example list of topics with unreaded posts. 
If user decide and open any of that topics then automatically it's marked as read and will not show inside that list again when he click on unread posts. Plus the possibility to mark all as read. 
I was thinking about maybe showing unread posts only from last 30 days, so data would not be so big.

The obvious and best solution would be making this inside objects embedded inside arrays, every array would have userid and timestamp of last view of specific topic, then i would just compare timestamp of the last post in thread to timestamp of last view of that thread by the user.
Only 2-3 queries then would be needed to show results to the user.

So for example it would look like this:

`{
_id: uniqueObjectid,
id: topic_id,
topic: topic of the thread,
last_update: timestamp of last reply to that topic,
reads: [
{id: userid, last_view: timestamp of last view on this topic by user},
...
]
}`

I would delete all threads from this collection that have last_update field  older than 30 days.

Showing then unread posts for users would be very easy, just compare last_update with last_view for certain userid.

But it's not a good solution, from what i've read the way arrays are implemented in mongodb make that solution very slow. Imagine having last view of some topic for 1000 users, it means 1000 indexed array elements.
So it can't be done in arrays.

Here Asya from MongoDB describes why big embedded arrays should not be used [link](http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays)

I am having difficulties to think of any other efficient way of solving this issue.